# Timeout period in Webservices

Tags: web-services

I need to change the timeout period of my webservice which was invoked by .net console application.

How to change the timeout period.

Its not hosted in IIS. Its single WSDL. I dont want to write any code. I need to change it in app.config

Answer (score 2):

Most web services eventually derive from WebClientProtocol.  This class has a [timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx) property that can used to alter the timeout.  Set it before invoking the service and it should do the trick.

Example

```
void SomeMethod() {
  SomeWebService v1 = new SomeWebService();
  v1.Timeout = 1000;
  v1.AWebServiceCall();
}
```

Comment: Either this is correct and we're all baffled why such a question was asked... or he only has control of the web service and wants to do this from inside the web service and doesn't understand it's not possible.

Comment: His post mentions app.config vs. web.config so I'm guessing it's client side